# Styling a Checkbox with Bootstrap and Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm looking for a simple way to do the following:

Make the checkbox bigger (width and height css do nothing)
Make a border that follows the rounded edges (border css does nothing)
Change the fill color when checked (background-color css does nothing)

So far all the answers I've seen either don't work, or require adding some exterior css and js files, which I then have to figure out how to style as well.  Any simple css to do this?

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

This had several cool and easy to modify examples, all in CSS.